# Calling a new function every time .each goes through 3 cycles

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I have an Jquery script that loads an XML file and spits out the contents. However, I'd like to format these contents into a table, with 3 columns per row. Currently, it makes one long row and I haven't found anything on google about calling in a new function after .each has loaded several items.

To reiterate, I want to execute *function newrow()* after *if(hideproduct == ""){}* has successfully executed 3 times.

```
var product_xml = "xml/products_loaded.xml"
function xmlParser() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: product_xml,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        function newrow(){
            $("#output").append("</tr><tr>")
        }

        $(xml).find("SAVED_EXPORT").each(function(){

            var productcode = $(this).find("productcode").text()
            var productname = $(this).find("productname").text()
            var productprice = $(this).find("productprice").text()
            var hideproduct = $(this).find("hideproduct").text()

            if(hideproduct == ""){
                $("#output").append("<td class='product' id='" + productcode + "'>"
                + "<a href='/i/" + productcode + ".htm' title='" + productname + ", " + productcode + "'>" + productname + "</a><br>"
                + "<span><font class='text colors_text'><b><span class='price'>Our Price</span>: </b></font> $" + productprice + "</span><br>"
                + "<img src='/v/vspfiles/photos/" + productcode + "-1.jpg' border='0' alt='" + productname + "'>"
                + "</td>");;

            }
        })      
    }
})
}
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who has an idea on how to solve this.

Comment: You are appending broken markup  `$("#output").append("</tr><tr>")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing is that you need a counter variable outside of the `.each` to store state:

```
var count = 0;
```

since you can't store state variables using local `var` declarations *inside* the `.each` callback function.

Then, inside the `if (hideproduct ...)` block, count the number of times it was called:

```
++count;
```

and if necessary, call the function

```
if (count === 3) {
    newRow();
    count = 0;
}
```

---

As it happens your `newRow()` function won't work anyway, because you can't create unbalanced HTML tags using `.append`.

A better solution would be:

```
var tr = null;
var count = 0;

$(xml).find("SAVED_EXPORT").each(function() {
     if (hideproduct === "") {
         if (tr === null) {    // create a new row
             tr = $('<tr>').appendTo('#output');
         }

         tr.append(...);       // add your content

         if (++count % 3 === 0) {
             tr = null;        // force a new <tr> on the next iteration
         }
     }
});
```

Note how a new `<tr>` is only created when necessary, and then the new content in your `<td>` elements are added directly to that, and not to `#output`.

Comment: @JackCole I just noticed that the `if (tr === null)` test needs to be inside the `if (hideproduct === "")` test, and updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    var i = 1;
    $(xml).find("SAVED_EXPORT").each(function(){

        [...]

        if(hideproduct == ""){
            [...]
            if(i%3 == 0)
                newRow();
            i++;
        }
    });
```

I am not sure exactly where you want to test the "3-test" but you get the idea! Basically, the i%3 == 0 test will check if i is a multiple of 3 (0,3,6,9...).